# angular material design toast for forms

Tags: angularjs, toast, material-design

I got an user login form, where it should show a toast message if authentication is failed. Here is my controller.

I dont want to initiate the toast with a button click as per the documentation. The toast message should be username and password doesnot match.

**controller**

```
app.controller('userCtrl',function($scope,$mdToast,$animate){
$scope.signin = function(credentials){
        console.log(credentials);
             $mdToast.show(
             $mdToast.simple()
        .content('Simple Toast!')
        .position($scope.toastPosition)
        .hideDelay(3000)
);
};
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks.I got it.

```
 app.controller('userCtrl',function($scope,$mdToast,$animate){

$scope.signin = function(credentials){

        console.log(credentials);
   $mdToast.show({
          position: "bottom right",
          template: "<md-toast>Toast !</md-toast>"
        });

};


});
```

did the trick.